# How to convert list of nested dictionary to pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data containing nested dictionaries like below:

```
mylist = [{"a": 1, "b": {"c": 2, "d":3}}, {"a": 3, "b": {"c": 4, "d":3}}]
```

If we convert it to pandas DataFrame,

```
import pandas as pd 

result_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(mylist)
print(result_dataframe)
```

It will output:

```
    a   b
  0 1   {'c': 2, 'd': 3}
  1 3   {'c': 4, 'd': 3}
```

I want to convert the list of dictionaries and ignore the key of the nested dictionary. My code is below:

```
new_dataframe = result_dataframe.drop(columns=["b"])
b_dict_list = [document["b"] for document in mylist]
b_df = pd.DataFrame(b_dict_list)
frames = [new_dataframe, b_df]
total_frame = pd.concat(frames, axis=1)
```

The total_frame is which I want:

```
    a   c   d
0   1   2   3
1   3   4   3
```

But I think my code is a little complicated. Is there any simple way to deal with this problem? Thank you.

Comment: `df_data = [{"a": el["a"], **el["b"]} for el in mylist]`

Comment: @TomWojcik Hi, how about if the dictionary has many keys

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `dict comprehension` with `pop` for extract value `b` and [merge dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38987):

```
a = [{**x, **x.pop('b')} for x in mylist]
print (a)
[{'a': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3}, {'a': 3, 'c': 4, 'd': 3}]

result_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(a)
print(result_dataframe)
   a  c  d
0  1  2  3
1  3  4  3
```

Another solution, thanks @Sandeep Kadapa :

```
a = [{'a': x['a'], **x['b']} for x in mylist] 
#alternative
a = [{'a': x['a'], **x.get('b')} for x in mylist]
```

Comment: This is a really elegant solution, but unfortunately I haven't been able to extend it to take in an arbitrary list of columns, since unpacking is not allowed inside a dict comprehension (e.g. `[{**x.pop(k) for k in x.keys()} for x in mylist]`. Is there an easy way to use with an arbitrary list of columns?

Comment: @economy Now I am on phone only, because holiday, so the best create new question, also with sample data and expected output, thanks.

Comment: Not a safe way. `x.pop` destroyed the original dicts.

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar problem to this one. I used `pd.json_normalize(x)` and it worked. The only difference is that the column names of the data frame will look a little different.

```
mylist = [{"a": 1, "b": {"c": 2, "d":3}}, {"a": 3, "b": {"c": 4, "d":3}}]
df = pd.json_normalize(mylist)
print(df)
```

Output:

|  | a | b.c | b.d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 3 | 4 | 3 |

Comment: It works for me. It is an elegant solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Or by applying `pd.Series()` to your method:

```
mylist = [{"a": 1, "b": {"c": 2, "d":3}}, {"a": 3, "b": {"c": 4, "d":3}}]
result_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(mylist)
result_dataframe.drop('b',1).join(result_dataframe.b.apply(pd.Series))

   a  c  d
0  1  2  3
1  3  4  3
```

Comment: @jezrael ok, noted. :)

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to write a function that accepts your `mylist` and converts it 1 nested layer down and returns a dictionary. This has the added advantage of not requiring you to 'manually' know what key like `b` to convert. So this function works for all nested keys 1 layer down.

```
mylist = [{"a": 1, "b": {"c": 2, "d":3}}, {"a": 3, "b": {"c": 4, "d":3}}]
import pandas as pd

def dropnested(alist):
    outputdict = {}
    for dic in alist:
        for key, value in dic.items():
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                for k2, v2, in value.items():
                    outputdict[k2] = outputdict.get(k2, []) + [v2]
            else:
                outputdict[key] = outputdict.get(key, []) + [value]
    return outputdict    

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dropnested(mylist))
print (df)
#   a  c  d
#0  1  2  3
#1  3  4  3
```

If you try:

```
mylist = [{"a": 1, "b": {"c": 2, "d":3}, "g": {"e": 2, "f":3}}, 
          {"a": 3, "z": {"c": 4, "d":3}, "e": {"e": 2, "f":3}}]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dropnested(mylist))
print (df)
#   a  c  d  e  f
#0  1  2  3  2  3
#1  3  4  3  2  3
```

We can see here that it converts keys `b`,`g`,`z`,`e` without issue, as opposed to having to define each and every nested key name to convert