# Missing column value when merge tables in python

Tags: python, sql, pandas, join, merge

I'm trying to merge 3 tables, namely **history**, **history_value** and **hocvien** to retrieve the columns, namely **['ngaybaoluu', 'ngayhoclai','lydo','hv_fullname','action', 'object', 'hv_coso']**. The problem is that my python result come out with no value for the column **['ngaybaoluu']**. I have tried the same inner join in SQL and get the desired result. Why is this the case? Please help me.

Python code (product result with no value for column **ngaybaoluu**)

```
# import necessary packages
  from urllib.request import urlopen
  import pandas as pd
  import json
  import requests

#Get a response and conver to json
req = requests.get('linktoAPI')
req_json = req.json()
# History_value table 
df = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(r['history_value']) for r in req_json)
history_value = df[['ketoan_id', 'lop_id', 'lydo','hv_id', 'ngayhoclai', 'ngaybaoluu', 'huyhopdong', 'chinhanh' ]]

# History table
response = urlopen('https://office.ieltsvietop.vn/api/get_data/history')
history = pd.read_json(response)
# Hocvien table
response = urlopen('https://office.ieltsvietop.vn/api/get_data/hocvien')
data_json = json.loads(response.read())
hocvien = pd.DataFrame(data_json)
display(hocvien.columns)
# Merge history_value to history using (ketoan_id)
history_value_history = history_value.merge(history, on ='ketoan_id', how ='inner',suffixes =('_left', '_right'))
display(history_value_history.columns)
# Merge history_value_history to hocvien using (hv_id)
history_value_history_hocvien = history_value_history.merge(hocvien, left_on = 'hv_id_right', right_on ='hv_id', how = 'inner')

display(history_value_history_hocvien[['ngaybaoluu', 'ngayhoclai','lydo','hv_fullname','action', 'object', 'hv_coso']])

print('Success')
```

SQL code (produce desired results)

```
SELECT hv_fullname,ngaybaoluu, ngayhoclai, ketoan_id, hv_coso, action, object, lop_id
FROM history_value
join history using (ketoan_id)
join hocvien on hocvien.hv_id = history.hv_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not getting any matching data to merge on for this line:

```
history_value_history = history_value.merge(
    history,
    on='ketoan_id',
    how='inner',
    suffixes=('_left', '_right')
)
```

I wrote some code to get the 'ketoan_id' in history_value that has data, and check if any are in the history df. It was empty for me. Since I can see that there are matching data, I checked the data types and found that some were strings, not numbers. If you look at the contents of ids_with_vals you will notice that they are strings. Once I converted all of the dataframes, it worked. The types can really catch you sometimes.

```
# Create mask to find 'ngaybaoluu' rows that are False
mask = history_value['ngaybaoluu'].isna()
# Use an anti-mask to get the ids that you are tyring to merge on.
ids_with_vals = history_value.loc[~mask]['ketoan_id'].to_list()
# Create a mask of the df you are merging to see if there is any data.
mask = history['ketoan_id'].isin(ids_with_vals)
# I get an empty df.
history.loc[mask]

history_value = history_value.astype({'ketoan_id': 'float'})
history = history.astype({'hv_id': 'float'})
hocvien = hocvien.astype({'hv_id': 'float'})
```

Comment: thank you, the thought of inappropriate datatype did not cross my mind. Have a nice day